# Stuttering animations and videos with Ubuntu 20.04 and nvidia

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, graphics, video

Everything is in the title. I have more information so I edit the question and the title.

1. With a old PC having an old video card (nvidia 950 I think) and Ubuntu 20.04, I don't have any problem at all with the same distro and the same drivers 455
2. I also have a recent ultrabook with Ubuntu 20.04 with a "standard laptop 2D video card" and videos run smoothly.
3. The correct keyword is *screen stuttering*.

I do have this problem **on the same computer** having a recent video card with Ubuntu 20.04 and not with Windows 10. I use for the test a HDMI connexion with a refresh rate at 70 Hz and the website https://www.testufo.com/refreshrate.

With Windows 10:

[image]

With Ubuntu 20.04:

[image]

As you can see, something goes wrong with Ubuntu. The detected refresh rate should be 70 Hz, not 60 Hz.

Using the website https://www.testufo.com/ghosting, sometimes the ufos stop and restart with Ubuntu due I guess to the difference of refresh rate. Everything runs smoothly with Windows 10, or with Ubuntu 20.04 on an old PC with a old nvidia video card or with an ultrabook with a standard 2D video card.

> How can I fix that please ? Googling *screen stuttering ubuntu* did
> not help so far.

**Note 1**: vsync is fully supported by linux. don't pay attention to this message.

**Note 2**: I have this stuttering problem while playing videos (e.g. youtube), and windows games in compatibility mode with proton; I did not notice the problem with native linux video games.

Comment: I'm using the same driver (on Arch linux) and no problems. Can watch films and youtube. Shouldn't be much difference (but my card is much older .. GeForce GTX 760). Just use a distro that don't use gnome

Comment: @kanehekili Well actually, that has to do with a gnome extension indeed :-). See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution ! I had installed the gnome extension [NVIDIA GPU Stats Tool](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1320/nvidia-gpu-stats-tool/) to test my new video card (a 2060 instead of a 1060), the temperature, the fan speed, etc... By disabling the extension, everything runs smoothly (e.g. the ufos).